# Php carbon - add days without weeks

Tags: php, date

I have a function to add days with carbon, the problem is that I want not add days of weeks.

This is my function

```
function addDaysWithoutWeeks($dateTimeString='',$days=0)
{
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTimeString, 'Europe/Madrid');
    return $date->addDays($days);
}
```

For example if I'll add 3 days to:

```
2018-08-24 the result should be 2018-08-29
```

How to can delete or omit the weeks when add days.?

Comment: Do you mean skip the weekends? Only add business days?

Comment: I think he means add only weekends(`I want not add days of weeks.`). Not sure tbh.

Comment: Logic isn't clear either put some detailed explanation complete with terminologies or add some more examples.

Comment: @aynber I need skip weekends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
function addDaysWithoutWeeks($dateTimeString='',$days=0)
{
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTimeString, 'Europe/Madrid');
    return $date->addWeekdays($days);
}
```

Comment: I need add days but skip weekends @vamsi

Comment: @Alexd2 above code will skip weekends. It will only add weekdays(Mon-Fri)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late and already answered but now Carbon has `addWeekdays()` function.